# Can we have Generics in Property?

Tags: c#, generics

I need help with this.

I want to create a filter. This filter takes in an Input Type and Output Type. 
How do I specify this in C#?

```
//Input is the current Filters Input Type
//Output is the current Filters Output Type. This Output will be the next filter's Input
//NextOutput, is the Next Filters Output

public interface IFilter<Input, Output, NextOutput>
{
        public IFilter<Output, NextOutput, HowDoIDeclareHere> NextFilter{ get; set; }
        Output Execute(Input input);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is `HowDoIDeclareHere` meant to be?

Comment: the thing about generics is that they are meant to be *predictable*; presumably the next filter could be any of a *range* of things, so there is no deterministic next-next-output (i.e. `HowDoIDeclareHere`); if you can't *define what it is*, you won't be able to express it to the compiler.

Comment: That type would be the NextFilter's Output type which I wont know so i need another generic

Comment: You would probably need a method like `GetNextFilter<HowDoIDeclareHere>()`. Would that work for your scenario?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks will relook at my implementation to make it simpler

Comment: @John Oh wait yes hahah damn, i think that would work

Answer (score 0):

Properties can use generics, like any field and function can. But properties only have a single type for input and output. They were designed to work like fields in as many cases as possible (missing only the out/ref arguments). Breaking that part would be a major issue here.

If you want different types:
- you would have to use get/set functions
- maybe a tuple that has both input and output type
- or two different properties - on set and one get only

However the whole question is extremely confusing. It sounds like you got more then one layer of XY Problem.

Properties are usually the wrong way to go about Filtering anyway. Usually you do that with a function. Something like a  `bool Match(InputType Input)` function.

Your function is doing not (just) filtering, but also a conversion. That sounds like you need a [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.converter-2).

Or maybe what you want is more in the Area of Input Validation? If so, Interfaces like [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo) are teh droids you should be looking for. Maybe combiend with MVVM style encapsulation?

Edit:

Based on yoru comments, something like this would do:

```
public interface IProcess<InputType, OutputType>{
    OutputType Process (InputType, Input);
}
```

From this one you can create "Processor" instances that implement it. You will need to write the actuall function code anyway:

```
public StringToIntProcessor : IProcess<string, int>{
    //Code omited
}
```

Aside from setting up a (bunch) of queues, I see no way to optimize or generalize it.

Comment: I am trying to do a Pipe and Filter pattern in c#. But I want it to be able to accept Different inputs and outputs. Thinking how to do this.

Comment: @RStyle That sounds like a bunch of `OutputType Process(InputType)` functions, called in a chain. Somewhat like you would chain Tasks. You could make a Interface for that, if you really want to. But Properties still seem like a wrong way.

Comment: @RStyle I wrote some example code. I can not think of any other Codification. And even that seems to go way overboard. Anything you could do with that, you could just do with a Basic Action and some Generic Queues.
I would guess you would have to give us a specific example, so we can figure out why